# I've managed to install pillow for Python3 but I get a weird response when trying to import Image. I'm a complete beginner sorry

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm getting...
My Result Is 1.9185207550537833
My Other Result Is 12.0
Universe Age 14000000000
x = 1, y = 2, z = 3
q = 10, p = fred, z = 20
What is the meaning of life?  It is 52

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: Just when I use

Comment: Sorry - getting use to the system.  
I'm just using:

from PIL import Image

Comment: and I get:
My Result Is 1.9185207550537833
My Other Result Is 12.0
Universe Age 14000000000
x = 1, y = 2, z = 3
q = 10, p = fred, z = 20
What is the meaning of life?  It is 52

Comment: ps (thanks by the way... ) Also when I try to run Image I then get the following error at the end

..."/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/decimal.py", line 3, in <module>
    from _decimal import *
AttributeError: module 'numbers' has no attribute 'Number'. Did you mean: 'number'?
[Finished in 1.4s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python3 -OO -u "/Users/vince/Documents/FRACTALS/python_work/plot.py"]
[dir: /Users/vince/Documents/FRACTALS/python_work]
[path: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]

Comment: ps.  Also same issue (incl strange txt and AttributeError) with this short code: (and thanks for looking!)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

squares = [1,4,9,16,25]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(squares)

plt.show()

Comment: Finally... Just noticed that matplot works when I type the commands directly into the terminal - but not when I run the file through the terminal.  Any ideas?  Thank you!!

Comment: I've solved it!  I cleared out my working directory of all python programmes and __pycache, and started afresh!  There must have been a conflict with one of my other python programmes (been writing a lot of short routines as I'm doing a 'crash course'!  Anyway, thanks for spending time looking at this.  Lesson learnt!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.